# Pass -Dpig.notification.listener argument to Pig action in Oozie (Oozie client build version: 3.3.2-cdh4.7.1)

Tags: oozie, oozie-coordinator

I want pass -Dpig.notification.listener argument to Pig action in oozie. But when I am doing this the pig is failing and there is no clear error description. Below is the Pig action snippet. Any suggestion how to pass listener to pig action.

```
<action name="FinalReport">
        <pig>
          <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
          <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
              <prepare>
                    <delete path="${nameNode}/home/hadoop/surjan/path" />
            </prepare>          <script>${nameNode}//home/hadoop/surjan/wf/pigs/FinalReport.pig</script>
            <param>inDate=20160430</param>

        </pig>
        <ok to="success" />
    <error to="kill" />
</action>
```

EDIT: I found the solution for passing the -D arguments. Just in case if anybody is facing same issue.

```
    <action name="FinalReport">
<pig>
    <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
    <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
    <prepare>
        <delete path="${nameNode}/home/hadoop/surjan/path" />
    </prepare>
    <configuration>
        <property>
            <name>pig.notification.listener</name>
            <value>com.surjan.util.counter.MyListener</value>
        </property>
    </configuration>
    <script>${nameNode}//home/hadoop/surjan/wf/pigs/FinalReport.pig</script>
    <param>inDate=20160430</param>
    <argument>Dpig.notification.listener=com.surjan.util.counter.CounterListener</argument>
    <archive>archive/mycounter.jar#mycounter</archive>
</pig>
<ok to="success" />
<error to="kill" />
```

```
enter code here
```